# How can we fix this mobile menu?

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu

We have taken over a project from previous developers and have some bug on the mobile menu we can't seem to figure out.

Mobile menu always has sub-menus opened and you cant close them at all.

**Code handle we could trace:**

```
jQuery('.menu-icon').on('click', function(e){
    jQuery('.main-navigation').toggleClass('menu-active');
    jQuery('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Any recommendations for us to just get the mobile menu working again? If we simply remove this the menu burger icon stops working completely to open the mobile menu.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: It's probably a css property. Check there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.